# C# - get JSESSIONID site ftp erro 401

Tags: c#, http-request, ftp, header, response

Não consigo pegar o JSESSIONID para baixar um arquivo de um ftp.
Preciso dele pois se eu colocar JSESSIONID fixo o arquivo baixa, caso contrário dá erro 401 não autorizado. Porém esse id muda.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "senha");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

O JSESSION só vem preenchido quando da o erro, quando eu tento algo do tipo "GetCookies()" ou "HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies" vem como null.
Ja tentei com WEBCLIENT tambem.

Comment: posso estar muito enganado mas eu nunca vi um ftp precisar do jsessionid, mas de qualquer forma, pra você conseguir esse valor você precisa criar um webresponse a partir do seu request, nele possivelmente vai estar o jsession entre os cookies

Comment: eu faço ali em request.GetResponse() mas da erro 401 não autorizado